# AWS Opswork Chef Fatal Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

We are trying to install python using OpsWork. Installation happens correct but in the end we get the message:

Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140715-9783-k2dw6u" returned 2
[2014-07-15T10:29:19+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

What can we be doing wrong?

Final Snippets of the output is below:

```
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/_exceptions.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/handler.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
STDERR: configure: WARNING:

By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".
If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache/Python-2.7.1/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7346: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache/Python-2.7.1/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7301: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
*** WARNING: renaming "crypt" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/crypt.so: undefined symbol: crypt
*** WARNING: renaming "nis" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/nis.so: undefined symbol: yp_master
*** WARNING: renaming "crypt" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/crypt.so: undefined symbol: crypt
*** WARNING: renaming "nis" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/nis.so: undefined symbol: yp_master
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140715-9783-k2dw6u" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140715-9783-k2dw6u" returned 2
[2014-07-15T10:29:19+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had that error happen before.

Solution 1 - I needed to upgrade make tools. Also needed to ensure that the python wasn't already installed.

Solution 2 - ( horrible one ) Also if all things fail, simply add the line into the BASH stanza:

```
bash "install python...." do
  ..
  ignore_failure true
  ..
end
```